# Which number is larger if $f'(x)$ is a differentiable increasing function for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-approximation

Suppose $f'(x)$ is a differentiable and increasing function for all $x$. Which number is the largest and why? $f(4+\Delta x)$ or $f(4)+f'(4)\Delta x$?

I believe $f(x)$ must be concave up everywhere since the derivative is increasing, but I am not sure how to figure out which of those is larger based on that. Would the tangent like approximation be $f(4+\Delta x)$ or $f(4)+f'(4)\Delta x$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent line approximation at $x=4$ is $f(4)+f'(4)(x-4)$.  You probably mean $x-4$ by $\Delta x$.  It cannot be $f(4+\Delta x)$ as this can not be linear-a straight line does not have increasing derivative.

You are right that $f(x)$ is concave up everywhere.  Does that mean it is above or below the tangent line?

Comment: if its concave up then this would mean that f(x) is above the tangent line, so would this would make the tangent line approximation less I do believe?

Comment: @user59714:  that is correct.